# FDO Geometry to GeoAPI Geometry

Tags: shapefile, c#

I doing a project on Shapefile. I am trying to convert FDO Geometry to GeoAPI Geometry.

suggest me.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'OSGeo.FDO.Common.Exception' occurred in OSGeo.FDO.Geometry.dll

Additional information: Unsupported geometry type. I get this error

Comment: Welcome to GSE. Please use the "edit" button to update the question with details about the software and environment. Comments are used to solicit information from the original poster (OP), not for the OP to add information.